# CSS Pyramid and text under each pillar

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have designed the following pyramid with CSS and its supposed when a user clicks on each of the pillars a text/div section to appear under the pillar...However, this text/div section should have its own CSS and format , so the problem right now its that the text/div section under the pillar its affected as child element from the CSS  of the pyramid...I tried to exclude it but still isn't working as its supposed.

```css
.pyramid {
  width: 400px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 360px;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(50% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
  -webkit-transition: 1.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: 1.5s ease-in-out;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.pyramid__section {
  flex: 1 1 100%;
  background-color: #3EB7FD;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 0 rgba(61, 74, 62, 1);
}

.pyramid__section:nth-of-type(even) {
  background-color: lightgray;
}

.pyramid__section:hover {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.pyramid:not(.mindText) {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="pyramid">
  <div class="pyramid__section ">Mind</div>
  <div class="mindText">Automate your sleep tracking & optimisation by using an OURA ring. Optimise your sleep & wakefulness hormones. Maximise your sleep recovery. Maximise your wake-up energy. Customise KPI habits, that play the most significant role for YOUR sleep. Leverage
    other gadgets & tools to optimise your environment for optimal sleep.</div>
  <div class="pyramid__section">Body</div>
  <div></div>
  <div class="pyramid__section">Nutrition</div>
  <div class="pyramid__section">Sleep</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Maybe the *[The Details disclosure element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/details)* will work for you.

Comment: thank you! it seems a interesting choice! i ll see if it can works!

Answer (score 0):

This seems a typical use case for the [The Details disclosure element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/details). Click some element (*summary* text) and disclose some other element (*disclose* text).

I converted your code to use the `details` and `summary` elements to show how it could work. Drawback is that details stay 'open' when another `summary` gets clicked. But, I inserted a little JS that closes already opened details. Simply remove the JS if you don't care about closing already 'open' details.

snippet:

```js
var currentDetail;

document.querySelectorAll('details>summary').forEach(el => {
    // this event triggers before <details> 'toggle' event
    el.addEventListener("click", event => {
        const closest = event.currentTarget.closest('details');

        if (closest.open) { /* about to trigger 'toggle' */
            currentDetail = null; // all menus closed
        }
        else { // not null and different menu
            if ((currentDetail) && (currentDetail != closest)) {

                currentDetail.removeAttribute('open'); // close current open menu
             };
             currentDetail = closest; // save new opened menu
        }
    });
});
```

```css
/* ADDED CODE */
details {
  padding-top: 1rem; /* just eye-candy */
}

details>summary {
  list-style: none; /* removes disclosure triangle */
  cursor: pointer;  /* makes sense, right? */
}

.pyramid__section {
  text-align: center;
}
/* end ADDED CODE */

.pyramid {
  width: 400px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 360px;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(50% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
  -webkit-transition: 1.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: 1.5s ease-in-out;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.pyramid__section {
  flex: 1 1 100%;
  background-color: #3eb7fd;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 0 rgba(61, 74, 62, 1);
  text-align: center;
}

.pyramid__section:nth-of-type(even) {
  background-color: lightgray;
}

.pyramid__section:hover {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.pyramid:not(.mindText) {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="pyramid">
  <details class="pyramid__section">
    <summary>Mind</summary>
    Automate your sleep tracking & optimisation by using an OURA ring. Optimise your sleep & wakefulness hormones. Maximise your sleep recovery. Maximise your wake-up energy. Customise KPI habits, that play the most significant role for YOUR sleep. Leverage
    other gadgets & tools to optimise your environment for optimal sleep.
  </details>
  <details class="pyramid__section">
    <summary>Body</summary>
    Body details
  </details>
  <details class="pyramid__section">
    <summary>Nutrition</summary>
    Nutrition details
  </details>
  <details class="pyramid__section">
    <summary>Sleep</summary>
    Sleep details
  </details>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your support! I am lacking also some experience in JS so its good to get a idea from your code! 
However, when i click on the "mind" pillar it doesnt react at all. No showcase of the inside text.
Or if i add more text on any <details> of the code it still encounters the same problem as my initial post... Text getting trap inside the triangle of the pillar

Comment: @Nick87 I reread your question a few times, but from that text it is not clear the `details` should be outside the pyramid. Please rework your question. For the 'mind' to appear you have to 'click' the `summary` text (just like the others). There may be just too little to click on... It is working for me, though.